# Ionic 4 custom environment file

Tags: angular, environment-variables, ionic4

I am working with Ionic 4 project. I have different environments(test, testB, prob, dev ecc..). I have created all the file inside the environment folder: **environment.dev.ts, environment.testA.ts, environment.testB.ts** etc. Is there any way to set the correct environment while building or serving(on the browser) the project(maybe something like --env=testA like angular?)? Only thing I can find is --prod, which is only for the production environment, but in this case, I have more than 2 environments.

Answer (score 3):

You should check your package.json file.
My package.json looks like the following:

```
  "name": "name",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
   "lint": "ng lint",
   "e2e": "ng e2e",
   "build-prod": "ng build --prod --progress false",
   "build-dev": "ng build --env=dev --aot=true --output-hashing=all --sourcemaps=false --extract-css=true --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer=true --progress false",
   "build-preprod": "ng build --env=preprod --aot=true --output-hashing=all --sourcemaps=false --extract-css=true --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer=true --progress false",
   "build-dev2": "ng build --env=dev2 --aot=true --output-hashing=all --sourcemaps=false --extract-css=true --named-chunks=false --build-optimizer=true --progress false"
},
```

In angular-cli.json there is an environment key:

```
"environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts",
    "preprod": "environments/environment.preprod.ts",
    "dev2": "environments/environment.dev2.ts"
  },
```

In Angular 8 you should check angular.json:

```
"configurations": {
        "production": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }, "preprod": {
          "fileReplacements": [
            {
              "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
              "with": "src/environments/environment.preprod.ts"
            }
          ],
          "optimization": true,
          "outputHashing": "all",
          "sourceMap": false,
          "extractCss": true,
          "namedChunks": false,
          "aot": true,
          "extractLicenses": true,
          "vendorChunk": false,
          "buildOptimizer": true,
          "budgets": [
            {
              "type": "initial",
              "maximumWarning": "2mb",
              "maximumError": "5mb"
            },
            {
              "type": "anyComponentStyle",
              "maximumWarning": "6kb",
              "maximumError": "10kb"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is working fine with the Angular project but not with Ionic, and I am working with Ionic with Angular.

Comment: I have an ionic app with Angular and in the root there is an angular.json which contains the above mentioned

Comment: Thanks for the edit and answer again. But, there is not angular-cli.json file in ionic 4. Btw, I resolved after some research. The logic is similar in Ionic 4 but with some differences, I also post my solution also here to help others.

Comment: Yes it was the second part where I have mentioned: _In Angular 8 you should check angular.json_.
You made a  mistake, angular.json(as I mentioned) instead of angular.js

Comment: What about Ionic project with React?

Comment: @CoveredEe Would be great if you could post your answer on how you fixed it!

Comment: @SyedWaqas readded my solution. You can also use ionic serve --configuration = inv_name

Answer (score 1):

I resolved after some testing! Solution for Ionic 4:

1. Create all the files you need with environment variables inside the folder **src/environments**. Example environment.live.ts, environment.test1.ts, environment.test2.ts, etc
2. Update **angular.js** file in the root folder;

   ```
     "configurations": {
          "production": { ... } // already there for production
          // Add for your custon environments files here
          "testA": {
             "fileReplacements": [
               {
                 "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                 "with": "src/environments/environment.testa.ts" //Name of your file
               }
             ]
          } ... // Do this for every environment on every build you need
     }
   ```
3. Import environment file inside your project where you need:

   **import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';**
4. To pick a different environment while building or serving: **ionic serve -- -c=testA** same logic for build etc... This will automatically replace the environment file with the correct one, in this case with file related to **testA** environment.